# Can you extract the data matrix from pheatmap in R?

Tags: r, pheatmap

I created a heat map based off of gene microarray data and then used the pheatmap to cluster the data and output a heatmap.

Is there any way to output the clustered data of the heatmap in a matrix form to an excel file?

Comment: If you save the heatmap as an object you might be able to access the data. Take a look at the structure (`str()`), it could very well be there

Answer (score 0):

One way is to reproduce the data clustering directly. The default input parameters to `pheatmap` specify Euclidean distance and hierarchical clustering.

The code below reproduces the clustering that `pheatmap` would do on the test matrix. The contents of `reordered` are what would be plotted by `pheatmap`.

```
# load clustering library
library(stats)

# example matrix from pheatmap documentation
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] = test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) = paste("Test", 1:10, sep = "")
rownames(test) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")

# cluster and re-order rows
rowclust = hclust(dist(test))
reordered = test[rowclust$order,]

# cluster and re-order columns
colclust = hclust(dist(t(test)))
reordered = reordered[, colclust$order]
```